# Strange bug with Reducer

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, reducers, react-context

I maintain an object array in my Context that keeps track of validation errors in my input form.  Here's an example of it populated with one object:

```
validationErrors = [{id: 0, message: 'Already exists', name: 'vin'}]
```

The message is displayed underneath the input element in question, prompting the user to enter a new value.

When the user does so, an async call is made to check if the new value already exists in the DB.  Before that call is made, a call is dispatched  to this reducer:

```
    case CLEAR_VIN_INFO: {
      return {
        ...state,
        validationErrors: [...state.validationErrors.filter(
          validationError => validationError.name !== 'vin' || validationError.id !== action.id)],
        vehicles: state.vehicles.map((vehicle: Vehicle) => {
          if (vehicle.id === action.id) {
            return {
              ...vehicle,
              makeModelYear: ''
            };
          } else {
            return vehicle;
          }
        })
      };
    }
```

It's doing a few things but the main thing I want to focus on is that this specific validation error, with `id: 0` and `name: vin` are removed from `validationErrors`.  Watching what's happening in Chrome DevTools, I can indeed confirm that it is being removed.  In other words, `validationErrors` is set to an empty array.

But upon returning from the async call, the following code produces unexpected results:
`console.log(validationErrors.find(error => error && error.name === 'vin' && error.id === vehicle.id));`
It reveals the following: `{id: 0, message: 'Already exists', name: 'vin'}`
How is this possible?

By the way, checking `validationErrors` in Chrome DevTools again shows that it's still empty!

My intuition is telling me that this bug is due to a previous version of `validationErrors` being referenced instead.  I've never encountered this before though, so am not sure what to do.

Any ideas?

Update: As a sanity check of sorts, I made a call to this reducer instead:

```
case CLEAR_ERRORS: {
  return {
    ...state,
    validationErrors: []
  };
}
```

This one absolutely clears `validationErrors` before the async call is made.  Yet, upon returning from the async call, `validationErrors` is still populated!  Now I'm completely baffled.

Comment: Without a small reproducible example, this is really not answerable.

Comment: Try making a small reproducible example on codepen or codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch the state and access validationErrors inside your async call, then it should be good... but need more explanation in your question.

Comment: Venkata Paven Kumar MHS : I think you're onto what the problem is.  That said, I have a question: Given that `validationErrors` is a property in the associated Context, why isn't it working for me to call the `CLEAR_ERRORS` reducer before making the async call?

Note: I tried dispatching to `CLEAR_ERRORS` immediately upon returning from the async call but this didn't work.  I'm not surprised because the change is not instantaneous.